# Ionic 3- ios Loss focus

Tags: ionic3

I have a problem with the emulator of xcode. When keyboard is hidden, the inputs loss the focus and I can not write in it. In real device I dont have any problem. Any help will be appreciated. I had tried with cordova 3.9.2 - 3.12.0

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem in the compilation I changed my package.json and rebuild, and it worked